# Matlab coder build error when trying to access structures

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a nested structure with some fields labeled as `L1`, `L2` etc. I try to access a substructure within the structure using the following code.

```
lfield = lfidcalc(le);
substruct = bmstruct.(lfield);
```

Since `le` changes its value in every iteration, `lfield` also changes its value from `L1` to `L9`.

However, when I try to build this code to generate a C++ executable, I get the following error.

> Non-constant expression or empty matrix. This expression must be
>   constant because its value determines the size or class of some
>   expression. In this context, the value of the string must be known.

Can anybody please try to help me sort out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's causing the error message you're seeing, but in any case MATLAB Coder does not support accessing the fields of a structure using dynamic field names.

Perhaps that is the direct cause of what you're seeing, perhaps not: but in either case you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not all correct matlab code can be converted to C/C++. Especially this kind of (very handy) code. Have you put '%#eml' on the second line of your function? It indicates that you will generate code. From matlab website: " We use the %#eml directive to turn on the MATLAB M-Lint code analyzer and check the function code for errors and recommend corrections."

Comment: I remember `%#codegen` to be used for this purpose: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/adding-the-compilation-directive-codegen.html . Any difference between them?

Comment: @Sam Roberts. Yes I got to know it later. Now I have to use static field names instead by using a switch case.